# Кривое форматирование в HTML после Gulp

Tags: html, gulp, include

Только учусь, использую Gulp сборку, собирал по гайдам с YouTube.

При сборке форматирование HTML  в результирующем *index.html* съезжает и его трудно читать.

Подключаю HTML-модули в *index.html* с помощью **"gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0"** следующим образом:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

@@include('html/head.html', {
'title': 'Home'
})

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        @@include('html/header.html')
        @@include('html/main.html')
        @@include('html/footer.html')
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Сам модуль выглядит вот так:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="container"></div>
</header>
```

В ответ получаю вот такую красоту:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
    <div class="container"></div>
</header>
        <main class="main">
    <div class="container"></div>
</main>
        <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container"></div>
</footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

А именно проблемы с табуляцией у блоков. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему установкой плагина **gulp-html-beautify**